# JQplot- Editing built in Axis Values

Tags: jqplot

I tried Implementing Line Graph using JQPLOT. i want to disable the X-AXIS values which are dynamically built up in the code. I was able to hide the Y-Axis in Jqplot.min.css and I want to do the same for the X-axis .. Can someone please suggest something?

Any other logic to give our own X-axis values is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here the link where you can get your answer:
[Jqplot Docs](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html)

Look at the options for axes, ticks[] can contain your own x-axis values.
different show options can hide your x-axis or just the tixks also.